# NAT and LAN networking

Tags: networking, lan, nat

I've got a little bit confused with LAN networking, so I hope that someone can answer me for few theoretical questions:

Let's assume that I have a little LAN in my home. I'm writing a simple program that will send a 'Hello world' string to a IP that is given by the user. Now, the user is able to send either to the world-wide network, or to the LAN members. 
My question is:

1. Behind the scenes, where and by who, the seperation between the packets destinated to the outside world and to the LAN is made?
2. NAT: we are still working with the program. A user just sent a packet to the outside world, which handled by the router with NAT routing technique. While the packet was in it way to the destination, the NAT table in the router resets. What will happen once the reply packet from the destination will reach the router?

Thanks in advance,
Idan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The separation is made by your network card based on your IP configuration.

Your IP configuration is composed of:

- An IP address e.g 192.168.1.1
- A mask e.g 255.255.255.0
- A gateway e.g 192.168.1.2

From the IP address and the mask the card deduce the range of address of your LAN (e.g 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.255), if the destination address is in the range of address, the network card send directly the packet to the destination machine. If the destination address is outside of the range, the packet is sent to the gateway. The gateway (which is basically your router) will forward the packet, eventually using NAT.

2. If the NAT table has been reset, the router cannot know to which machine the incoming packet is for, it will most probably drop it.

Comment: OK, thank you!
But I have one more question.
Lets assume that my net card looping through the addresses and finds out that the destination is within the local network, and lets assume that i have a seperate switch in my network. The net card will send it to the switch, for it to route it to the right computer. In that case, how does the net card know what is the address of the switch?

Comment: A switch is transparent in this case. Your net card send the IP packet within an Ethernet packet targeted to the MAC address of the net card of the target computer. The switch will receive the Ethernet packet and forward it.

Comment: If the switch is transparent, it means that theoretically, without switch the packet will also get to it destination?

Comment: A switch is just a clever hub, and a hub can be seen as direct electrical connection of the Ethernet cables: All devices connected on a hub see themselves as all connected on the same cable. A switch is "clever" because it only forward the packet on the cable the target machine is on. So yes you can replace a switch by a cable and the packet will still reach its destination.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much !

Comment: @IdanOfek, "_A switch is just a clever hub..._" That is really disingenuous. A hub. is a layer-1 device, the same as a cable. A switch is a layer-2 device, and it makes its decision which way to switch a frame based on the layer-2 destination address on the frame. A hub, like a cable, doesn't look at anything traveling through it, but a switch updates its MAC address table, and it will intelligently switch frames to specific interfaces based on that table. Hubs and switches operate at different network layers. Its the same thing as calling a router a clever switch, and that is simply not true.

Comment: @Ron Right, but I did not think this level of detail was needed. The full answer to this question is a complete course on IP and Ethernet, which I do not think is the expected answer. And yes from the IP level point of view a switch is just a clever hub, even if the cleverness happens one level above.

Answer (score 0):

1. if the packet/message is sent to a host on the same subnet/vlan then it will be sent to to the host directly because it is at one hope distance (in layer3) from the origional host that's why the router is not included (however, behind the scenes it can be at many hopes in layer2 if there are swithes in between. A host has ARP table containing the MAC addresses and a switch has "Mac Address Table" which will forward the packet from a switch port to another till it reaches the second host without passing through the router).
2. If the NAT table in the router resets, obviously there is no way to track back which received packet belongs to whom and they will be dropped.